# What's wrong in my test code?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I have a step definition cucumber like this

```
find("div#cycle_form table").should have_content(append_row_to_table_tag("day_num", "hour", "hour_night"))
```

Method append_row_to_table_tag returns string

```
"<tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>"
```

and view

```
%div{:id => "cycle_form", :class=>"list_form"}
  = link_to("Add",nil,:id=>"create_row_cycle")#,:onclick=>"$('div#cycle_form table').append('#{append_row_to_table_tag("day_num", "hour", "hour_night")}');return false;", :href=>"")
  %table
    %th day
    %th hour
    %th hour_night
    %th edit_button
    %th delete_button
```

cucumber fails

```
expected there to be content "<tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td> 
<td>data</td></tr>" in "day hour hour_night edit_button delete_button\ndata data data 
data data" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

How can I test adding element to page with JavaScript with capybara?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capybara's `have_content` method deals with text content - not HTML markup.  In general Capybara operates on top of the DOM so you'd be better off using it's selectors to query individual elements of the table you want to assert against.

If you want to compare the contents of a Cucumber table against an HTML table, I found [a nice example](https://gist.github.com/1334262) of that.

If you really want to test that specific markup is contained on the page, I believe you can drop down to Nokogiri's native representation and access the HTML that way, or even assert against `page.body` to get the full HTML source, but I consider both of these to be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gem like Jasmine to test Javascript. [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/261-testing-javascript-with-jasmine)'s a nice screencast showing how it works.

Comment: Thanks for replay,Skydreamer! I learned cucumber with capybara.. How can test with capybara? and why i get this notice "expected there to be content"

Comment: Problem resolved with

    find("div#cycle_form table").text.should have_content(append_row_to_table_tag("day_num", "hour", "hour_night"))